# Как Разбить столбец с местом проживания на страну/город/регион?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

У меня получается такая таблица (изначально есть только **столбец [регион]** и **['пол']**). Хотелось бы получить по итогу колонки:

1. Город;
2. Субъект;
3. Страна.

|  | пол | Регион | Страна | Город | Область | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ж | Россия, Томская область, Томск | Россия | Томск | Томская область | True | Областной центр |
| 2 | ж | Россия, Москва | Россия | Москва | Москва | True | Областной центр |
| 3 | м | Не указано |  | Не указано |  | False | Районный город |
| 4 | м | Не указано |  | Не указано |  | False | Районный город |
| 5 | м | Россия, Самарская область, Самара | Россия | Самара | Самарская область | True | Областной центр |
| 6 |  | Россия, Пермский край, Пермь | Россия | Пермь | Пермский край | True | Областной центр |
| 7 | ж | Не указано |  | Не указано |  | False | Районный город |
| 8 | м | Россия, Татарстан, Казань | Россия | Казань | Татарстан | False | Районный город |
| 9 | м | Россия, Нижегородская область, Дзержинск | Россия | Дзержинск | Нижегородская область | False | Районный город |

С горем пополам сделал это через 3 функции:

```
    def country(data):
    split_text = data.split(',')
    return split_text[0]
```

Это вытащить страну.

```
    def subject(data):
    split_text = data.split(',')
    a1 = split_text[1::2]
    return ''.join(a1)
```

Это вытащить субъект.

```
    def city(data):
    split_text = data.split(',')
    return split_text[-1]
```

Это город.
Потом применяю эти функции поочерёдно и получаю три новых столбца:

```
    users['Страна'] = users['Регион'].apply(country)
    users['Субьект'] = users['Регион'].apply(subject)
    users['Город'] = users['Регион'].apply(city)
```

Не критично, но вообще хотелось бы **сделать одной функцией** это. По применению получить три новых столбца сразу, чтобы сохранился столбец ['Пол']. Как-нибудь можно это реализовать?

Далее чтобы понять, что город является областным центром столбец ['b'] (первые 3 буквы) промежуточно приходится получить столбец ['a'] проверяющий равенство и выдающий `boll`:

```
users['a'] = users['Субьект'].str[:4] == users['Город'].str[:4]
```

Получаемая колонка ['a'] по сути не нужна, однако лучше ничего не получается сделать. Хотелось бы сделать ее проходной ( в конечном df будет отсутствовать - все же не нужна).

Ну и собственно на основании true/False создается столбец ['b']:

```
def gg(ff):
if ff == 1 :
    return 'Областной центр'
else:
    return 'Районный город' 

users['b'] = users['a'].apply(gg)
```

Все бы хорошо, однако есть записи с пропусками (3, 4 строки ) и их бы в столбец b стоило бы переместить с названием "Не указано". Думал это сделать сравнением со столбцом ['Город'], но как это записать в функцию `gg`  **ума не приложу**.

Вообще здорово было бы написать одну **единую функцию** , которая сразу по применению поделит столбец ['Регион'] на все меня интересующие.

Благодарю!

Comment: приведите в вопросе исходные данные в воспроизводимом виде.

Comment: @strawdog, `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep="\t", index_col=0)` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [natasha](https://pypi.org/project/natasha/):

```
from functools import lru_cache
from natasha import MorphVocab, AddrExtractor

morph_vocab = MorphVocab()
addr_extractor = AddrExtractor(morph=morph_vocab)

@lru_cache(maxsize=2048)
def parse_addr(addr_str, addr_extractor=addr_extractor):
    ext = addr_extractor.find(addr_str)
    if not ext:
        return pd.Series(dtype=str)
    res = pd.Series(
        {part.type if part.type else "город": part.value 
         for part in ext.fact.parts},
        dtype=str
    )
    return res


res = df.join(df["Регион"].apply(parse_addr))
```

результат:

```
In [41]: res
Out[41]:
   пол                                    Регион  Страна       Город                Область      a                b  страна        область      город      край
1    ж            Россия, Томская область, Томск  Россия       Томск        Томская область   True  Областной центр  Россия        Томская      Томск       NaN
2    ж                            Россия, Москва  Россия      Москва                 Москва   True  Областной центр  Россия            NaN     Москва       NaN
3    м                                Не указано     NaN  Не указано                    NaN  False   Районный город     NaN            NaN        NaN       NaN
4    м                                Не указано     NaN  Не указано                    NaN  False   Районный город     NaN            NaN        NaN       NaN
5    м         Россия, Самарская область, Самара  Россия      Самара      Самарская область   True  Областной центр  Россия      Самарская     Самара       NaN
6  NaN              Россия, Пермский край, Пермь  Россия       Пермь          Пермский край   True  Областной центр  Россия            NaN      Пермь  Пермский
7    ж                                Не указано     NaN  Не указано                    NaN  False   Районный город     NaN            NaN        NaN       NaN
8    м                 Россия, Татарстан, Казань  Россия      Казань              Татарстан  False   Районный город  Россия            NaN     Казань       NaN
9    м  Россия, Нижегородская область, Дзержинск  Россия   Дзержинск  Нижегородская область  False   Районный город  Россия  Нижегородская  Дзержинск       NaN
```

Comment: Мне нравится ваш подход! А можно объединить край и город в один столбец ( ну то есть будет столбец область/край/республика?  Например у Казани из за этого пропал субъект федерации ( Татарстан же республика).

И вопрос областного/республиканского центра остался открытым(

Comment: @convair36, это вам лучше обратиться к разработчикам модуля `natasha` ;)